# Error in image upload

Tags: php, curl, multipartform-data

I want to post some data including a image.I am using curl in php for this.My code is below-

```
 $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://postacity.co.uk:8080/shine/pp/upload/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    $post = array(
        'creatorid' => '119',
        'userfile' => '@/temp/fgf.jpg',
        'notice' => 'Image1',
        'catid' => '1',
        'title' => 'bookofzeus',
        'boardid' => '332',
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    else {
        echo $response;
    }
    }
```

Every time i am getting the same error

> **Error: failed creating formpost data**

Am i doing any mistake.I have searched for this problem but still no solution found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the file is the problem: `'@/temp/fgf.jpg'`

You should take a look at this bug gescription: [Bug 50060 - failed creating formpost data if post array value starts with @](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50060)

The solutions of this problem for example at [php freaks](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/37353-solved-curl-file-upload-failed-creating-formpost-data-error/).

And use **absolute** path to the files.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this its working

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, _VIRUS_SCAN_URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    // same as <input type="file" name="file_box">
    $post = array(
        "file_box"=>"@/path/to/myfile.jpg",
        "username"=>"foobar",
        "password"=>"secret",
        "submit"=>"submit"
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Also refer this url's

http://joshhighland.com/blog/2010/11/27/using-curl-and-php-to-upload-files-through-a-form-post/

http://blogs.digitss.com/php/curl-php/posting-or-uploading-files-using-curl-with-php/